# Update a UITable in a custom UICollectionView cell from a different cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, xib, nib

I have a `UICollectionView` with 4 customs NIBs.  In one cell I tap and track the position of the tap via tap gesture.  In another cell I have a `UITableView`  How do I update the `UITableView` from a different cell?  By update, I mean add a row to the `UITableView`.  Is this a job for notifications or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail on what you’re trying to do: what information do you want to convey to the table view (presumably it is something to do with details of the tap gesture)? What does your data model look like? What code have you tried so far? Happy to help but some more detail would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I solved the problem and meant to delete the question.  Thanks again.